# Replace a pattern in CSV file Python

Tags: python, regex, csv, replace

I have multiple CSV files that could represent similar things in multiple ways. For instance, 15 years can be written either as age: 15, age (years): 15, age: 15 years (these are all the patterns I've seen till now). I'd like to replace all those with 15 years. I know how to do it when I know the actual age or the column number, but the age is definitely different for each occurrence and the column is not fixed. The csv files could be like below:

CSV1:

```
h1,h2,h3
A1,age:15,hh
B3,age:10,fg
```

Desired CSV1

```
h1,h2,h3
A1,15 years,hh
B3,10 years,fg
```

When ever its just age: 15, its definitely years and not months or any other unit.

Comment: For the age field will the numbers just suffice? You can use the `str.translae` method if so. Create a table that maps letters to empty strings. An example is [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm)

Comment: @b10n: That sounds like a good idea...except you've left out a lot of details -- so I suggest you post an answer with some actual code in it.

Comment: @dan: How do you propose determining which column to fix?

Comment: @martineau By "which column to fix" if you mean which column in the file to use, to be frank I have no answer because I have multiple files, each processed by researchers from all over the world. So the format is not the same.

Comment: @b10n I need "years" following the number.

Comment: @dan: If you don't know which column needs fixing, then I don't see a solution -- otherwise there are ways that would probably work as far as reformatting the data within a specfic column goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.sub` like below,

```
re.sub(r'(,|^)(?:age\s*(?:\(years\))?:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:years)?)(?=,|$)',
       r'\1\2 years', string)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/3)

Example:

```
import re
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i in reader:
        print(re.sub(r'(,|^)(?:age\s*(?:\(years\))?:\s*(\d+)\s*(?:years)?)(?=,|$)', r'\1\2 years', ','.join(i)))
```

Output:

```
h1,h2,h3
A1,15 years,hh
B3,10 years,fg
```

**OR**

```
for i in reader:
    print(re.sub(r'(,|^)[^,\n]*age\s*:[^,\n]*\b(\d+)\b[^,\n]*', r'\1\2 years', ','.join(i)))
```

Comment: I don't think it needs to be that complicated.

   `re.sub(r'age.*?: (\d{1,2})[^,]*', r'\1 years', text)`

Comment: i made a regex to satisfy these `age: 15, age (years): 15, age: 15 years` conditions only.

Comment: True, but long regular expressions can be really hard to debug.

https://regex101.com/r/hK1uH1/5

Answer (score 1):

Use the translate table methods in the string module.

```
import csv
from string import maketrans
from string import ascii_uppercase, ascii_lowercase
delete = ascii_uppercase + ascii_lowercase + ":"
tran = maketrans("", "")

with open("infile.csv", "rb") as infile, open("output.csv", "wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in reader:
        #assuming the second field here
        row[1] = row[1].translate(tran, delete) + " years"
        writer.writerow(row)
```

I generally prefer `string.translate` over regex where applicable as it's easier to follow and debug.

Comment: @martineau thanks for the heads up on translate. You were right.

Answer (score 0):

Its a guessing game, but if the rule is that you want to convert anything that has the word "year" and some decimal number, this should do.

```
import re

_is_age_search = re.compile(r"year|age", re.IGNORECASE).search
_find_num_search = re.compile(r"(\d+)").search

outdir = '/some/dir'
for filename in csv_filenames:
    with open(filename) as f_in, open(os.path.join(outdir, filename), 'w') as f_out:
        writer = csv.writer(f_out)
        for row in csv.reader(f_in):
            for i, val in enumerate(row):
                if _is_age_search(val):
                    search = _find_num_search(val)
                    if search:
                        row[i] = "%d years" % search.groups()
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you. Its just that the word "year" may or may not be there. However, I could try it with the word "age".

Comment: @dan - you're right. added a regex search that can do multiple string compares.